# When phone is on RTL mode whet is the (0,0) point on the View?

Tags: java, android, view, translation

When my phone is on RTL mode, and i want to use **setTranslationX** method, to move the **View** to the left, should i use positive x or negative x as the method argument?
I know that when phone is on LTR mode, (0,0) is the left upper side of the View. But which point is consider to be (0,0) when phone in RTL mode?

Comment: The coordinate system doesn't change; i.e., (0, 0) is still the top-left corner. (You could've easily found this out by testing, btw.)

Comment: @MikeM., while debugging i look for an attribute and didn't find. Thank you!